# Jquery causes unintended DB row creation in cake

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, cakephp

I have this jquery code in a view, relating to my uploads controller:

```
function screenshot(){

var dataUrl = renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/png");
$.post("picturepicker", {dataUrl: dataUrl, uploadnumber: 2


 }

}
```

It successfully sends data to this function:

```
public function picturepicker(){
        ...

if($this->request->is('post')){
        define('UPLOAD_DIR', WWW_ROOT . 'img/');  // increase validation
        $img = $_POST['dataUrl'];  // Tried $this->request['dataURL'], retrieved 'dataURL' just fine
        $upload = $_POST['uploadnumber']; // tried $this->request['uploadnumber'], did not retrieve 'uploadnumber' 
        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
        $data = base64_decode($img);
        $file = UPLOAD_DIR . $upload . '.png';  // UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
        $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

        print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

Which works fine, except that every time I ran the javascript, a new database row is created. Since I have no create function, I imagine that somehow jquery is inadvertently calling this function:

```
public function upload(){

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        //var_dump($this->request->data);
        $this->Upload->create(); 
        ....
```

However, I doubt that since the rows are still added even when I delete all references to the create function.

So why might this happen, and how should I fix it? I am suspecting that somehow the jquery code is calling *all* of my functions, and that I need to put an if block around any of the others that take post data. I have been told that this should not be the case, and that perhaps cake's routing is to blame. Alternatively, I might have missed something in the cake documentation - perhaps cake is set up to make a new DB row for EVERY post request, and I need to tell it not to somehow.

Comment: You should note that `$this->Upload->create()` *does not* create a DB row, it's merely a function to prepare clean data to save to the db. Functions like `save`, `set`, `update` and many more are intended to add rows to the DB, but `create` in no case will do that, so you need to re-check the actions that may be inserting data to the db, since the code you shared here doesn't have any reference to saving data.

Comment: Ah that's right. At any rate I was deleting the entire offensive functions - in this case the entirety of my edit and upload functions.

Comment: Share all the code for `picturepicker`, and if you've made modifications to `routes.php`, it may be useful to add it here too. Cake does not call *all* your functions, so that's not the error. Cake is also *not* set up to make a new DB row in any case unless you specifically save new data, so it's not an opt-out feature and you should not consider it as a possible reason for the error.

Comment: I found the error: it was an errant save, that was being called twice by my jquery call.

Comment: Glad you found it :) Could you answer the question and accept it, or delete it completely? To let others know you've found a solution

Comment: I'll answer it myself, when it lets me. The interface isn't popping up for me (not enough time? rep?)

Comment: Not enough time. I don't remember what's the time limit, should be hours.